# Labview : delete files having same extension

Tags: labview

I've been trying to delete files having same extension by using labview.

I am using delete.vi to delete files like below.

[image]

But, I want to delete all files having same extension.

Imagine a folder like below.

[image]

Here, I would like to delete all files having '.MASTER, .jou, .IFPDAT, . f06, .f04, .DBALL' as extension.

I would like to make an automatic file delete function like below.

[image]

Would there be any good examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use "List Folder" with wild-cards (using "pattern" input) to get an array of files. Then you have to delete files one by one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use System Exec.vi.
Here's an example to delete all DXF files in a folder:

[image]

Drawback: portability